# Is the HttpsServer expandable with web-Gui?

Tags: java, web, https

I have created some https-server with java se and in future i want to create some small web gui, where you can see some database entries. My question is, is it possible and practical to make this small webgui with java se? or should i change maybe to java ee with spring framework?

I used following code as basics:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q3732109;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;    
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
 }

 static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        String response = "This is the response";
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you a lot, Mira

Comment: What ever you write to the response it reaches request owner. What is your question ?

Comment: Why do you want to write your own implementation of a webserver and/or application-server? Have you checked out Apache Tomcat and JSP?

Comment: I tried to use java spring. but it was to oversized for my plan. i need some https handler, which receives https request and creates some small responses. for this intentions i thought it would be enough. the web gui is just a smallest part of my application.

Comment: I am honestly afraid you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Use Tomcat (or any other servlet container / application server) and Servlets/JSP (ideally applying the MVC pattern).

Comment: Maybe you are right. I thought, for my client-server architecuture it would be enough, but i red that sun* packages should not be used. so this is a second reason to use another way. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html